# Bootstrap: thumbnails within grid are too narrow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap's grid system for medium (md) screen size. When I paste code for thumbnails (Custom contents from getbootstrap.com), I get too narrow thumbnail (default text "Thumbnail label" exceeds thumbnail's right border at "Thumb-"). However, I want the thumbnail to have it's full size within grid system. The relevant code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>...</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop, the latest Firefox, Bootstrap is 3.3.7.

Comment: What is the goal of your output? The code above seems to split the row into 3 columns, THEN in the first column, it splits THAT row into 3 columns. So you're working with 1/9 width of the row. Is that what you intend to do?

Comment: The goal was to place three Thumbnails one beside the other, but I was wrong when just copying & pasting from getbootstrap.com. I removed the unecessary <div> tags and everything began to work;) Thank you :) P. S. Where is the "thank you" button here? You've earned it:)

Comment: Excellent! No worries, just pay it forward :)